# Undefined JS alert

Tags: javascript, php

I've got an **a-tag** which reads as this: (and there are number of a-tags being dynamically populated as this stays inside a PHP loop.)

```
echo "<a onclick='trygettheid();' class='mainList' id='main' href='index.php?idd=".$reK['catid']."'><div class='AS1'>".$reK['catdescriptor']."</div></a>";
```

and the JS function looks like below.

```
function trygettheid()
{
    var myvariable = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(myvariable);
}
```

The issue is when a click is triggered, the alert says **'undefined'** instead of the desired output of **'main'**

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Are you declaring your function before you assign it as a click handler?

Comment: @wogsland Yes, declaring before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the function `this` does not refer to the clicked element it may be `window` object. To fix it pass the reference as an argument to the function. Although there is no need to use jQuery since `id` can be get from element `id` property.

**PHP :**

```
 echo "<a onclick='trygettheid(this);' class='mainList' id='main' href='index.php?idd=".$reK['catid']."'><div class='AS1'>".$reK['catdescriptor']."</div></a>";
 //                       ------^------
```

---

**JS :**

```
function trygettheid(ele){
  //             -----^-----
  var myvariable = ele.id;
  //             ---^--^----
  alert(myvariable);
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you :) sorry I edited the earlier comment as I was too soon to jump in to a conclusion.